# Using a Python dict for a SQL INSERT statement for CX_ORACLE

Tags: python, sql, oracle, cx-oracle

convert a dictionary to SQL insert for the `cx_Oracle` driver in Python

```
custom_dictionary= {'ID':2, 'Price': '7.95', 'Type': 'Sports'}
```

I'm need making dynamic code sql insert for `cx_Oracle` driver from  custom dictionary

```py
con = cx_Oracle.connect(connectString)
cur = con.cursor()
statement = 'insert into cx_people(ID, Price, Type) values (:2, :3, :4)'
cur.execute(statement, (2, '7.95', 'Sports'))
con.commit()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a known set of columns to be inserted, simply use the `insert` with named params and pass the dictionary to the `execute()` method.

```
statement = 'insert into cx_people(ID, Price, Type) values (:ID, :Price, :Type)'

cur.execute(statement,custom_dictionary)
```

If the columns are dynamic, construct the `insert` statement using the keys and params
put it into a similar `execute`

```
cols  = ','.join( list(custom_dictionary.keys() ))
params= ','.join( ':' + str(k) for k in list(custom_dictionary.keys()))
statement = 'insert into cx_people(' + cols +' ) values (' + params + ')'
cur.execute(statement,custom_dictionary)
```

Comment: If I have  this dictionary: `custom_dictionary= [{'ID':2, 'Price': '7.95', 'Type': 'Sports'},{'ID':3, 'Price': '8.95', 'Type': 'Study'},... ]`  How can I use your solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas.read_json` method with iteration over list converted values through `dataframe` :

```
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle
con = cx_Oracle.connect(connectString)
cursor = con.cursor()
custom_dictionary= '[{"ID":2, "Price": 7.95, "Type": "Sports"}]'
df = pd.read_json(custom_dictionary)

statement='insert into cx_people values(:1,:2,:3)'
df_list = df.values.tolist()
n = 0
for i in df.iterrows():
    cursor.execute(statement,df_list[n])
    n += 1


con.commit()
```